# How to point domain to different host sub folder?

Tags: asp.net, database, dns, subdomain, hosting

I have a host and domain on [asphostportal.com](http://asphsotportal.com), and  I have a subdomain like: sub.domain.com.
Now my friend has another domain like frienddomain.com and he points to my host.

How can I point his domain to my subfolder sub?

Everytime he opens frienddomain.com, it will show my site on sub.mydomain.com.   Currently he shows my mydomain.com sites.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

When you purchase hosting from hosting provider, they are always gives us **Domain DNS Information** like below:

***Domain DNS Information***

```
Domain Name Server 1: ns1.abc.xyz.com
Domain Name Server 2: ns2.abc.xyz.com
```

**OR**

```
Domain Name Server 1 IP: 2.1.17.146
Domain Name Server 2 IP: 2.1.12.56
```

Gives above DNS to your friend to update his existing domain DNS with yours DNS. Your friend would update it his domain purchase account and it will take 12-24 hours to update DNS. It depends on domain purchased company.

After successfully set your hosting DNS in your friend's account, you have to add your friend's domain `frienddomain.com` in your hosting control panel and point your `sub` folder as a root for domain `frienddomain.com`

Here are some reference links:

1. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sva42KVt0-o
2. https://www.123-reg.co.uk/support/answers/Video/Domains/how-do-i-point-my-123-reg-domain-name-to-my-3rd-party-website-3874/
3. https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/28148/point-domain-to-new-host-changed-nameservers-now-what

Please let me know if you have any questions.